# Where to find Java Mission Control and VisualVM on Ubuntu (OpenJDK 8)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

I installed OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`, and it was installed to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

Where can I find the Java Mission Control (I think called `jmc`) and VisualVM (I think called `jvisualvm`) programs?

I assumed both to be installed with the JDK:

- [The Java Mission Control page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) states that "Starting with the release of Oracle JDK 7 Update 40 (7u40), Java Mission Control is bundled with the HotSpot JVM."
- [The VisualVM page](https://visualvm.java.net/) says "March 18th, 2014: JDK 8 has been released and is available for download here. It contains Java VisualVM tool based on VisualVM 1.3.6."

What am I missing? Are both only part of the Oracle JDK, or did I use the wrong install command?

If they are not part of the OpenJDK, can I download them using `apt-get install`?

Comment: I see them in `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin` with the oracle JDK, if they aren't in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin` I guess they aren't part of the openjdk. Oh, and `jmc` and `jvisualvm`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Thanks for the correct names. And no, I don't see them in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`.

Comment: If you need them, it sounds like you should get the oracle jdk. I recommend the [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) PPA.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: "Need" is probably the wrong word, I just want to be able to profile my application while running, with some heap visualization, and both seem suitable for this, so I just wanted to test them and play around a bit with them. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You can also try JConsole

Comment: The latest version can be downloaded here: https://jdk.java.net/jmc/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some OpenJDK distribution maintainers are now providing jmc builds like [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/jmc.html), [Amazon Corretto](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-jmc/releases) or [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-mission-control/).

Java Mission Control (jmc) is open source and hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc) and [openjdk.java.net](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc/) (as a Mercurial repository).

Official nightly builds are available [here](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/).

It is also rather easy to build jmc yourself using the instructions from the [readme file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc/file/b8e4bfe95f7c/README.md):

```sh
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc/
cd jmc/releng/third-party
mvn p2:site
mvn jetty:run
```

In a different terminal:

```
cd core
mvn clean install
cd ..
mvn package
```

After installing, you can close the Jetty server running in the first terminal.

Alternatively, you can use Docker to build jmc:

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run jmc
```

To launch jmc:

- on Linux: `target/products/org.openjdk.jmc/linux/gtk/x86_64/jmc`
- on macOS: `target/products/org.openjdk.jmc/macosx/cocoa/x86_64/JDK\ Mission\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/jmc`
- on Windows: `target\products\org.openjdk.jmc\win32\win32\x86_64\jmc.exe`

You should see a splash screen now:

[image: splash_screen_of_java_mission_control]

---

More info in this [blog post](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=1196).

Comment: `docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run jmc` worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Java Mission Control is an Oracle addon.  If you want to profile I suggest you use the OpenJDK and/or a commercial profile like YourKit.

> If they are not part of the OpenJDK, can I download them using apt-get install

You have to download it from the Oracle website after agreeing to their usage license.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean download the full Oracle JDK, which includes Java Mission Control?  I see this link (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) which leads on to the full JDK download, but no link to a standalone Java Mission Control download.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the build instructions provided by Steven is to use docker-compose to do the build:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc/
$ cd jmc/jmc/docker
$ docker-compose up
# Wait for the build to finish, then exit it with Ctrl-C
$ cd ../target
$ ls products/org.openjdk.jmc/
linux macosx win32
# Run the binary from the correct OS
$ ./products/org.openjdk.jmc/linux/gtk/x86_64/jmc
```