# Determine OpenJDK active GC type

Tags: garbage-collection, java

Does anybody know how to determine the active GC type(serial, parallel, etc.) via JMX in running OpenJDK 8 JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely based of my local machine it may likely be different from yours. Hopefully though it will help you find what you are after.

So its probably a good idea to download Java 1.8 Mission Control if not already installed. See the following Stack Overflow question.

- [Where to find Java Mission Control and VisualVM on Ubuntu (OpenJDK8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483804/where-to-find-java-mission-control-and-visualvm-on-ubuntu-openjdk8)

When you have Java Mission Control open you will want to select your running JVM, this can be found on the left tab under 'JVM Browser'

When you have selected your running JVM you should be able to select the option 'MBean Server'. Selecting this will open a Overview of your JVM, at the bottom of this page you should see multiple tabs, including 'MBean Browser'.

This tab will display you devices, applications or any resources that need to be managed by the JVM including the Garbage Collector.

You should be able then to filter the MBean Tree by searching for 'Garbage'

For more information about the Garbage Collection you can view the 'Memory' tab at the bottom. This will hopefully display you the GC Tables that contain the Garbage Collection data and descriptions. ( See second screenshot)

Hopefully if all is working as I expected you will be shown the MBeans for Garbage Collection such as my screenshot below.

[image: JVM Mission Control - GarbageCollector]

[image: Garbage Collection Memory Overview]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, so only the existence of a Bean can tell which one is active, right?

Comment: Hi there, no problem. I've made a slight change to my answer to include the 'Memory' tab. To answer your question, any MBeans you see in Mission Control are the currently active and running and these will be registered with the platform MBean server, so yes you are correct.