# How to monitor a java application using JDK Mission Control and OpenJDK 1.8?

Tags: java, jmc

I installed JDK Mission control 8.0.0 from the [Github](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc) repository or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167724/2096986). When I launch it I can only see the self JMC instance. My java application is not visible. I am using `openjdk version 1.8.0_252` and I launched my application using the JVM arguments

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

that does not have any effect or with

`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder`

that does not work.

The application does not launch. When I run the JMC with sudo I receive the message `The owner of /home/felipe/.config/ibus/bus is not root!` and still I cannot see my java applications.

I also found a [source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/monitoring/application_profiling.html#profiling-with-java-flight-recorder) that says to use these parameter together with OpenJDK 11:

`env.java.opts: "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=false,dumponexit=true"`

I can launch the java application with these parameters but the JMC does not listen to the application.

Comment: `When I run the JMC with sudo` - stop right there. Why `sudo` ?

Comment: because I was trying to use VisualVM and it only could listen my java pp using `sudo`. Anyways, I added the parameter `,filename=file.jfr` and I let the java application run for a while and when I finish it generates a `.jfr` file that I can open in JMC.

Comment: I have no experience on this, but I believe you need to obtain a Java implementation hat includes a back-port of JMC to Java 8. Azul Systems [provides this](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-mission-control/), and maybe other vendors.

Comment: I also tested using JDK 11 when I alternate the JVM in my machine using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and it didn't work.